# Manga or comic with magical animal companions? Specifically remember a one eyed crow/raven

Tags: story-identification, manga, webcomics

I recently had a vague memory of what I think may be either a manga or (web)comic. I don't THINK it was animated but I can't say for sure.

I remember a scene at some fancy party, probably rich people. I think magic is a thing in this story.
Everyone, or at least some have some sort of monstrous animal familiar/companion. I know there was a man with a large dog-like animal with him. He ended up talking with a woman with a raven/crow that had 1 central eye. The man was very braggy and talking down on her about, I think, a book about something important and how she would probably have never heard about it or doesn't understand.
I also think there was some making fun of her weak looking familiar?
But then she smugly revealed she's the writer of that book. The man got angry about it. But also her familiar grew large and monstrous and I think killed or at least attacked the guy's dog creature.

I don't even know who the main character is in this story. I don't think the woman is, but she is important, I believe, or evil.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Any idea when you would have seen this?

Comment: @DavidW ( i hope this is how i reply properly, idk the site that well yet ) i don't think it's SUPER long ago, but i do suspect a few years maybe. Honestly can't say for sure.. :s

Comment: @Red - You replied the correct way. :-) Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: I could possibly see "work", but I went for "rack" on the edit because it fits the idea and would match phonetically. Feel free to [edit] that to something more correct.

Comment: Do you have any idea where this scene would take place in the story? I.e. is it in the opening and thus introducing these characters and the setting, or does it take place more in the middle of the story?

Comment: @qazmlpok oops yeah thats a typo. It's ment to be "weak".  As for the scene. I honestly don't remember my memory isn't the best. I think it would be early story tho

Comment: @LogicDictates i can't recall if its in color or not, sorry

Comment: Heh, so I was wrong. My apologies.